# Preloader code - where to put it in the html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the code for my preloader:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".preloader").fadeOut("slow");;
});
```

My question is, where in the html document I should put the code. I've seen it done various different ways on different example websites. Some put the code inside script tags just after the `<head>` tag (before they declare their css), others put it inside script tags after importing css/other scripts so just above the closing `</head>` tag. Others put it inside a script tag just before the `</body>` closing tag.

**I'm sort of confused because the whole point of a preloader is to wait for the content to be loaded so should it not go right at the top, before css and other script imports inside the `<head>` tag?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to put all scripts at bottom of body for page rendering performance purposes

However since you are using a load event it doesn't matter. The code inside the load handler won't run until the window is loaded, regardless of where you place it in the page.

That event won't trigger until all the resources that exist in the html source are loaded ... css, scripts, images etc. It does not however know about any ajax or other asynchronous content you may be adding

note however that `$(window).load()` is deprecated and you should use

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $(".preloader").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

And if you aren't worried about images can use

```
$(function() {
    $(".preloader").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: Might be good to mention the `$(document).ready(...)` event, which fires when the DOM is ready, but not necessarily after every external resource loads. Might make more sense for OP.